# zoomed too far out and lost all of my objects

Tags: 3d-view

I zoomed too far out and lost my objects. I tried selecting an object and pressing ctrl ., but I don't have a numpad so it doesn't work. Is there another way I can reset my view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it without the numpad decimal (.) shortcut - select the object in the outliner, then go to the View menu (top left of the 3D Viewport) and pick "Frame Selected":

[image: Frame]

If you want change the shortcut key (perhaps to one you *do* have), you can find it in *Preferences > Keymap > 3D View > Frame Selected*

[image: FrameKey]